# How can I run a python fie written in atom editor directly in Terminal?

Tags: python, atom-editor

I am new to atom editor. I was wondering if by a single command I can directly run the file in the command prompt?
For example in Sublime Text 3, I made a custom Build system where I wrote these lines

```json
{
    "cmd": ["python", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python",
    "target": "console_exec"
}
```

Now just by `ctrl+b` the cmd opens up and the codes executes.
How can I do this in atom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There many ways to run an atom written python file in the terminal. 
The most common way to do this is to run it using python3 in the command prompt.

1. Save your python file as `.py`
2. Use `cd` to enter the directory with the python file
3. If on python 2 run: `python script_name.py` 
   If on python 3 run: `python3 scrip_name.py`

You can also use extensions to make this easier. Atom is a text editor, not an IDE, however certain extensions can provide some IDE capabilities to Atom. One of them is the `atom-python-run` extension. Here is the [installation instructions and documentation](https://github.com/foreshadow/atom-python-run/wiki/02-Getting-Started).

Comment: Yes I have tried script, the problem that I encountered with it is say for a simple Fibonacci series program, the script terminal won't accept large numbers and output error. Also, I wanted it to run in the terminal. Thank you for your answer though.

Comment: Just to clarify, do you mean the atom terminal or command prompt?

Comment: The command prompt. I am sorry if I was not clear, I will edit the question

Comment: You can use the steps described in the first part of the answer

Comment: Yes certainly, I can do that but like mentioned in the OP can I make a build or something so I can do it from the atom editor itself as I have done in Sublime?

Comment: Oh, let me check if there is an Atom extension for that

Comment: somebody had posted this plugin (but deleted their answer) called https://atom.io/packages/atom-python-run and it is perfect does this job. If you could add it in your answer or rather make another, I will gladly accept it. Thank you.

Comment: @Lucifer edited to include that extension!